# Joomla Development File Handling

Tags: php, model-view-controller, file-upload, joomla, file-handling

I'm making a simple MVC component for joomla following the hello world tutorial for the most part, with some some text fields and an image.

The text fields save but the "file" field does not, any ideas?

```
**Controller:**
    <?php
    // No direct access to this file
    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

    // import Joomla controllerform library
    jimport('joomla.application.component.controllerform');

    /**
     * MJob Controller
     */
    class MJobsControllerMJob extends JControllerForm
    {
    }

**Model:**

    <?php
    // No direct access to this file
    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

    // import Joomla modelform library
    jimport('joomla.application.component.modeladmin');

    class MJobsModelMJob extends JModelAdmin
    {
        public function getTable($type = 'MJob', $prefix = 'MJobsTable', $config = array()) 
        {
            return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
        }

        public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true) 
        {
            // Get the form.
            $form = $this->loadForm('com_mjobs.mjob', 'mjob', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));

            if (empty($form)) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            return $form;
        }

        protected function loadFormData() 
        {
            // Check the session for previously entered form data.
            $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_mjobs.edit.mjob.data', array());
            if (empty($data)) 
            {
                $data = $this->getItem();
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }

**view.html.php:**

    <?php
    // No direct access to this file
    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

    // import Joomla view library
    jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

    class MJobsViewMJob extends JView
    {

        public function display($tpl = null) 
        {
            // get the Data
            $form = $this->get('Form');
            $item = $this->get('Item');

            // Check for errors.
            if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) 
            {
                JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
                return false;
            }
            // Assign the Data
            $this->form = $form;
            $this->item = $item;

            // Set the toolbar
            $this->addToolBar();

            // Display the template
            parent::display($tpl);
        }

        protected function addToolBar() 
        {
            JRequest::setVar('hidemainmenu', true);
            $isNew = ($this->item->id == 0);
            JToolBarHelper::title($isNew ? JText::_('COM_MJOBS_MANAGER_MJOB_NEW') : JText::_('COM_MJOBS_MANAGER_MJOB_EDIT'));
            JToolBarHelper::apply('mjob.apply');
            JToolBarHelper::save('mjob.save');
            JToolBarHelper::save2new('mjob.save2new');
            JToolBarHelper::cancel('mjob.cancel', $isNew ? 'JTOOLBAR_CANCEL' : 'JTOOLBAR_CLOSE');
        }
    }

**VIEW (tmpl/edit.php):**
<?php
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
echo "<b>MJOB EDIT START</b><br>";
?>
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mjobs&layout=edit&id='.(int) $this->item->id); ?>"
      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="adminForm" id="mjob-form">
    <fieldset class="adminform">
        <legend><?php echo JText::_( 'COM_MJOBS_MJOB_DETAILS' ); ?></legend>
        <ul class="adminformlist">
            <?php foreach($this->form->getFieldset('details') as $field): ?>
                <li><?php echo $field->label;echo $field->input;?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="mjob.edit" />
        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can't really help if you don't provide any code. Could be a multitude of reasons.

Comment: Ho Lodder, it's a whole extension, so I'm not sure what code to post, I was looking at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415450/how-to-upload-a-file-in-joomla but I have no clue where that script is supposed to go, the model? The controller? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using Joomla! 2.5 based on the code provided.

So to retrieve a file that's been uploaded you will need to do something like:

```
$jFileInput = new JInput($_FILES);
$theFile = $jFileInput->get('jform',array(),'array');


// If there is no uploaded file, we have a problem...
if (!is_array($theFile)) {
    JError::raiseWarning('', 'No file was selected.');
    return false;
}

// Build the paths for our file to move to the components 'upload' directory
$theFileName = $theFile['name']['tablefile'];
$tmp_src    = $theFile['tmp_name']['tablefile'];
$tmp_dest   = JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/uploads/' . $theFileName;
$this->dataFile = $theFileName;

// Move uploaded file
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
$uploaded = JFile::upload($tmp_src, $tmp_dest);
// $uploaded contains boolean indicating success or failure
// $tmp_dest will contain final location of file if successful.
```

Comment: Where do I put this though? I can get PHP code to work but I have NO clue where to put this in Joomla. Does this go in the Model / Controller / etc?

Comment: Generally in keeping with Joomla!'s MVC it would go in the Model's prepareTable() or possibly in the Table's bind(). It would depend on what you're doing with the file being uploaded.

Comment: How can I put it into those functions without overriding the original, I tried doing something similar with the save() but it discards what it's supposed to do and only does what I tell it. Is there a way to extend default functions?

Comment: you can call the classes version of a function via `parent::somefunc()`

Comment: open a new question with the error details and relevant code so we can answer it properly, as for example code to look at Joomla! is the best resource.

Comment: I finally got this to somewhat work, but now i get a "Warning: Failed to move file!"

Comment: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851783/joomla-development-warning-failed-to-move-file-error

Comment: @anhnt glad it worked, the only thing with J3.3+ is that `JError` is deprecated so you will want to remove that eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure in your html form you have

enctype="multipart/form-data"

enabled otherwise you won't receive any files in php.